# Как в linq реализовать перегрузку SelectMany чтобы получилось вывести параметры в перечеслении

Tags: c#, linq

Дан следующий код:

```
List<string[]> teams = new List<string[]>
            {
                new string[]{"Лионель Месси", "Криштиану Роналду", "Златан Ибрагимович", "Роберт Левандовский"},
//команда 1
                new string[]{"Мохаммед Салах", "Паоло Мальдини", "Франц Беккенбауэр", "Мишель Платини"},
//команда 2
                new string[]{"Йохан Кройф", "Лев Яшин", "Дэвид Бэкхем", "Диего Марадона"} 
//команда 3
            };

            string l = Console.ReadLine();

            var result = ...

            foreach (var player in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Команда номер {player.TeamNumber}, {player.Name}");
            }
```

Реализуйте переменную result таким образом, чтобы получить коллекцию игроков, чья фамилия начинается со строки, записанной в переменной l (независимо от регистра), с номерами их команд (начиная с 1).

Что вводит пользователь:

```
м
```

Что получает пользователь:

```
Команда номер 1, Лионель Месси
Команда номер 2, Паоло Мальдини
Команда номер 3, Диего Марадона
```

Пытался решить с помощью такой конструкции

```
var result = teams.Where(f => f.Contains(l)).SelectMany((word, index) => word.Select(c => $"{c}, {index}"));
```

Но не могу понять как перегрузить SelectMany таким образом чтобы у меня в выводе текста были

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Команда номер {player.TeamNumber}, {player.Name}");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в перегрузку добавить переменные TeamNumber и Name чтобы я их смогу вызвать в перечислении

Comment: `var result = teams.Select((item, index) => (TeamIndex: index, Members: item.Where(member => member.ToLower().Split()[1].StartsWith("м".ToLower()))));` Дальше простым циклом `foreach (var item in result) Console.WriteLine($"Команда {item.TeamIndex+1}: {string.Join(",", item.Members)}");`

Comment: а как сделать перебор, чтобы без string.Join в переборе foreach чтобы как тут было. 
foreach (var player in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Команда номер {player.TeamNumber}, {player.Name}");
            }

Comment: `var result = teams.SelectMany((team, teamIndex) => team.Where(member => member.ToLower().Split()[1].StartsWith("м".ToLower())).Select(member => (TeamIndex: teamIndex, Member: member)));`

Comment: если вам нужно исключительно для вывода в `foreach`, то я бы просто использовал `foreach` вложенный в `for` :)